# WiFi Universal Repeater minimum range between devices

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-access-point, repeater

How does WiFi repeating works?

When I configured my Universal Repeater I had to type WiFi SSID and MAC of main AP.

Both are connected to same physical network. And what interests me most is how it exactly works.

My main consideration is how far can one be from another. If repeater takes signal from my client (phone) does it relay it to main AP via WiFi or via Cable?

I assume it must be within range of another, since the Repeater needs to see main AP. But if signal is very weak between Repeater and AP, will it use Ethernet to send data to AP to make it faster?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A WiFi **repeater** is like a person place between two other distant people. It needs to be in range of both so that it can hear both 'speak' and repeat that to the next person.

Communication is like this:

```
       Souce ---> repeater
                  repeater  ----> Original access point
```

Everything is transmitted twice. So speed is usually half the maximum speed you would get without a repeater.

Cave eats: That assumes two indetical setups and the repeater precisly in the middle. Practical speeds are likely to be a lot lower than having your laptop (source) right next to the access point. But possibly higher than without a repeater if you are very far away from the AP.

> will it use Ethernet to send data to

As I define the terms a repeater has no Ethernet or powerline or other cables. So it will/can not use them. There are other devices which do have these.

A device with an Ethernet network cable leading up to it and its own Wifi point would be either its own wireless access point of an extender (could be same device in a different mode).

And there are powerline adaptors which use the electricity network to do much the same.

Comment: I'm wondering what should I use. I got Network in my home and 2 Wifi AP. Not sure what would be better. To have Repater. 2 Separate SSID/AP or (if possible) to create 2 identical networks with same SSID?

Comment: With 2 separate SSIDs it is easier for the end user to know where (s)he is connected to. But 1 SSID means you can easily walk from one room to another and not get a disconnect. 

Thus it depends on how you want to use it.

Personally I use a powerline connection from the main router to the living room and in there I have an access poit with its own SSID (TL-WPA8730).  But I do not tend to walk around. I sit in one place and SSH/browse/mud/...